# Вернуть наиболее часто встречающееся записи в рамках каждой группы

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Необходимо для каждой группы страны определить самую популярную приставку для игр, на основе таблицы опросника.
Подскажите пожалуйста каким способом выполнить группировку.

| Country | Model |
| --- | --- |
| China | PC |
| Russia | Xbox |
| USA | PS |
| USA | PS |
| Germany | Xbox |
| Russia | Xbox |
| China | Xbox |
| USA | PC |
| Germany | PC |
| China | PC |
| Russia | PS |
| China | Xbox |
| China | Xbox |
| USA | PC |

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) .. GROUP BY country, model`

Answer (score 0):

```
with s (Country, Model) as
(select 'China','PC' from dual union all
select 'Russia','Xbox' from dual union all
select 'USA','PS' from dual union all
select 'USA','PS' from dual union all
select 'Germany','Xbox' from dual union all
select 'Russia','Xbox' from dual union all
select 'China','Xbox' from dual union all
select 'USA','PC' from dual union all
select 'Germany','PC' from dual union all
select 'China','PC' from dual union all
select 'Russia','PS' from dual union all
select 'China','Xbox' from dual union all
select 'China','Xbox' from dual union all
select 'USA','PC' from dual)

select Country, Model
from (select q.*, max(q.cnt) over (partition by q.Country) as max_cnt
      from (select  s.Country, s.Model, count(1) as cnt
            from s
            group by s.Country, s.Model
            )q 
      )
where cnt = max_cnt
```

| COUNTRY | MODEL |
| --- | --- |
| China | Xbox |
| Germany | PC |
| Germany | Xbox |
| Russia | Xbox |
| USA | PC |
| USA | PS |